# how to wrap each three list in a div?

Tags: jquery

I'm applying the following jquery to wrap it with a `<div class="col">` for each three `li`

```
var cells = $('.menu li');

    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i+=3) {
      cells.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='col' />");
    }
```

As this is so simple like this markup [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ramz2/)

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

For this markup also it works perfectly. [demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/Ramz2/1/)

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>one</li>
    <ul>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
    </ul>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <ul>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
    </ul>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

But when the ul is inside the li then the problem happens, like this markup: [demo3](http://jsfiddle.net/Ramz2/2/)

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li>one</li>
        <ul>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>

            <li>four             ------------
                <ul>                        |
                <li>two</li>                |
                <li>three</li>              | it's counting as 1 but I want
                <li>four</li>               | counted to be 5
                <li>five</li>               |
                </ul>           -------------
            </li>
            <li>five</li>
        </ul>
        <li>six</li>
    </ul>
```

So, how can I wrap every three li whatsoever it is nested within li, ul....

Comment: your marks seems to be invalid `div/ul` as child of `li`?

Comment: nesting a `div` element as a direct child to `ul` is invalid

Comment: thanks for informing that, I'll change the div with something but how can I wrap?

Comment: It sounds like you want to flatten the list, i.e. not have any nested `ul`s. I'd iterate through all of the `li`s first, adding them as children of the top `ul`, then remove all the `ul`s inside the top `ul`, and then use your `for` loop.

Comment: What is the purpose of this DOM manipulation? Do you always want to have the DOM look like this or only after some user interaction? If it's the first scenario, I'd suggest to serve the DOM as intended.

Comment: totally not getting your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var $menu = $('.menu');
var cells = $menu.find('li').detach();
$menu.empty();

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i += 3) {
    cells.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<ul />").parent().wrap('<li class="col"/>').parent().appendTo($menu);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nTk5K/)